# RadioButtonList Problems populating

Tags: vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I'm loading the radiobuttonlist from the page load event. The radiobuttonlist's are in the panel two, when I click submit in panel one; panel two becomes true and panel one becomes false. My radiobuttonlist seems to double itself in panel two.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    rblUserID.Items.Add("****")
    rblUserID.Items.Add("****")
    rblUserID.Items.Add(txtUserID.Text)
    rblUserID.Items.Add("****")

    rblPassword.Items.Add("12345")
    rblPassword.Items.Add(txtPassword.Text)
    rblPassword.Items.Add("asdfg")
    rblPassword.Items.Add("100101")

    rblYears.Items.Add("26")
    rblYears.Items.Add("20")
    rblYears.Items.Add(txtBirthDate.Text)
    rblYears.Items.Add("13")

    rblEmail.Items.Add("*****@mail.com")
    rblEmail.Items.Add("*****@mail.com")
    rblEmail.Items.Add("*****@mail.com")
    rblEmail.Items.Add(txtEmailAddress.Text)
End Sub
```

this is my html for the radiobuttonlist

```
<strike><asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPassword" runat="server">
        </asp:RadioButtonList></strike>
```

Im trying to make some form of a quiz doesnt seem to work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a `Button` , a `PostBack` is generated and the `Page_Load` is called again, make sure your `RadioButtonList` code is executed only once by Checking [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) property like this :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

 If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

    rblUserID.Items.Add("****")
    rblUserID.Items.Add("****")
    rblUserID.Items.Add(txtUserID.Text)
    rblUserID.Items.Add("****")

    rblPassword.Items.Add("12345")
    rblPassword.Items.Add(txtPassword.Text)
    rblPassword.Items.Add("asdfg")
    rblPassword.Items.Add("100101")

    rblYears.Items.Add("26")
    rblYears.Items.Add("20")
    rblYears.Items.Add(txtBirthDate.Text)
    rblYears.Items.Add("13")

    rblEmail.Items.Add("*****@mail.com")
    rblEmail.Items.Add("*****@mail.com")
    rblEmail.Items.Add("*****@mail.com")
    rblEmail.Items.Add(txtEmailAddress.Text)

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: omg thanks. i dont know if this is right tho I need to to probably loop but idk.  Protected Sub btnSubmitTest_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitTest.Click

        If rblUserID.SelectedValue = txtUserID.Text Then
            Correct.Visible = True
        ElseIf Not IsPostBack Then
            Correct.Visible = False
            Incorrect.Visible = True
        End If

    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like to me is that your code is doing exactly what it intends to do. Although, your description on what you are trying to accomplish is a bit confusing.

My guess is to check to make sure you haven't already added the items when the page validates again. Or try to make sure the event only loads once or pick a different event that loads the RadioButtonList.

Best of luck to you!